# Rspec comparisons: difference between should eq, match, be, ==?

Tags: rspec

Starting to use rspec assertions with cucumber and I've got the doubt about which way to make string comparisons. I've tried the following 4 methods and all of them seem to produce the same result, so I was wondering if one of the methods is better over the others?

And, is it easy to explain the difference between the 4 methods? Maybe with an example?

```
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should == 'Radio')
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should eq('Radio')
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should match('Radio')
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should (be 'Radio')
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the string comparison you are doing, `==` , `eq` and `(be .)` are basically the same.

The `match` is pattern matching and will match partials, so would match bRadiosity which would not be true for the other methods if that was the whole text in the `a` anchor tag

e.g.

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > a="text with radio"
 => "text with radio" 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > a.=='radio'
 => false
```

and

```
1.9.3-p194 :013 > b="radioz"
 => "radioz" 
1.9.3-p194 :014 > b.=="radio"
 => false 
1.9.3-p194 :015 > b.match "radio"
 => #<MatchData "radio">
```

Note:

```
== is ruby (which also has .eql? available though not shown here).
.eq is an rspec helper as is the (be .) construct
```

Personally I like `==` the best for string comparison.  Other folks prefer `.eql` because it differs more from `=` (stands out more, less confusion).  I may like `==` more as it sems a bit more portable across languages.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the explanation. And is there any difference between those operators `==, eq, (be .)` in any scenario, ie, in which particular cases should we use one of them over the others to make sure we receive the correct behaviour?

Comment: Please see http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.687916.13 for some additional info.